# pbuilder storing dependencies

Tags: debian, pbuilder, build-dependencies

I'm building only a limited number of packages, which have the same dependency set on every build. Unfortunately, pbuilder tries to install the dependencies on every rebuild instead of storing a prepared image and reusing it every time, for example.

Is there a way to enable such functionality? Can I somehow skip the long step of installing build dependencies if they didn't change between subsequent builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can chroot into your unpacked pbuilder environment using `pbuilder --login` and install whatever packages you like. Normally, all the changes you make there are thrown away again once you log out, but there also happens to be a `--save-after-login` switch which will cause all changes made to be included in the pbuilder chroot you logged into.

When doing that, I highly recommend to first copy the environment you'll be editing and only edit the copy. That way you'll still have a "clean" environment around that you can use to check that your packages correctly declared all their build-dependencies before uploading them to some archive. You can use pbuilder's `--basetgz` option (or `--basepath` when using cowbuilder) to switch between different chroots.